# How to mysql query different tables of different controllers in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have 4 controllers and one database. Each controller is associated with one table. I am not able to query in one controller if i have to access table of another controller. I get "table not found" error.

Comment: Well first if you want your controller to use methods of another controller you will have to extend it with your own controller or include it and then create it's instance. **BIG BIG BIG BIG NOTE**: Why on earth would you want to have controllers interact and why on earth do you keep your DB Pull/Push logic in your controllers ? **You should associate your Models with your tables and then your can use your Models i any controller multiple times.**

Comment: In a slight chance you wanted to say **Models** instead of **Controller** well then. Each model represents one DB table and it can query only that table unless you define a relation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the relations between the tables, using the associations:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

By adding the right colums to your tables (Foreign ID fields) and defining the model associations, you will be able to access all the fields from the related tables.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing to say the least. Are you having issues accessing different models inside different controllers or is this an association issue? In your controller, you can define what models your controller uses by setting $uses:

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

    $uses = array('User', 'File');

    public function index(){
        $results = $this->File->find('all');
    }

}
```